# Should I be concerned about a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, windows-services, memory-management

I'm new to writing Windows Services. I decided to write one that makes outbound calls through Twilio. I am utilizing using statements when I use a resource which implements IDisposable. I ran the service for a total of four hours so far and here is a look at my memory usage:

Start: 9k

15 Min: 10k

30 Min: 13k

1 hr: 13k

2 hr: 13k

3 hr: 13k

After an 30 minutes it seems to be consistent (between 13,100 and 13,200) but I am not sure why resources are still being allocated after the first 30 minutes. The OnStart() method initiates 4 timers and a few small objects. The construction of my objects certainly does not take 30 minutes. The timers just wait for a specific time, execute a query, then queue the results with Twilio and wait for the next event.

Should I be concerned about a memory leak at this point? Is this normal for such an application?

Comment: It's quite impossible to tell, since your memory usage is low the garbage collector probably never kicked in. Try running your service for a couple of days.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it's hard to be sure. Thanks for your help! It's installed on my test server and will be running over the weekend. I'll provide an update on Monday.

Comment: I agree with @zmbq. Just watch it for a few days and see what happens. The memory usage will fluctuate depending on what the code is doing and the garbage collector but should sit within a average range of values.

Comment: The CLR does not release memory immediately.  In fact, it may never release memory it allocates.  Allocation is hard.  Why release it when it isn't being needed by the system.  Grab a copy of CLR Via C#.

Comment: The question is valid, what's with the down votes?

Comment: Thanks Will, and Jon. Im downloading the CLR Profiler and ordered CLR Via C#. Jon- I'm not sure why people are so uptight about the question- It's not like I pasted my code and said 'Fix it' :). I got what I was looking for. I appreciate those that had input. I'll provide an update after a few days.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The numbers alone won't indicate anything but the question is still valid. He thinks their could be a memory leak, he provided what he thought would be useful info and wants others advice. Obviously others are able to offer help, which is the whole point of this site... (besides making money :) so the question is valid to me at least but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like you need to be concerned about a memory leak.

On a machine with several gigabytes of memory available, consumption of 13k of memory is ... trivially small. If this grows steadily and never decreases then you have a leak: otherwise, you're fine.

---

It's worth remembering that strings in the CLR are invariant, so every time you "change" a string a new copy is created and the memory allocated to the old version is marked as unused. So most programs churn through a bit of memory just in their usual day-to-day use: this is normal and only something to be concerned about in edge conditions such as *very* tight loops or huge collections or both.

Even then, the .NET garbage collector (GC) does a great job of sweeping up and consolidating this old memory from time to time.

There are some situations where strings (and other objects) can be allocated memory (and other resources such as file handles) that are not freed after use, and that's where you need to use `Dispose()`.

Comment: Thanks for a more detailed explanation. What your saying about strings makes sense, I just was expecting it to be a bit more constant.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An educated guess might be that the framework still allocates some things when you do HTTP requests and such.

I wouldn't be worried at this point, but if you really want to, you can always use [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) or another .NET memory profiler to see what's going on and if it's something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the CLR profiler and try commenting out my HTTP requests. I'll get back to you with the results on Monday.